# How do I use Feature Tags from Azure App Config in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, azure-app-configuration

I am attempting to use feature flags from Azure App Config in my Blazor application. I have been following this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-feature-flag-aspnet-core?tabs=core3x) from Microsoft to add them. I am successfully able to use them by injecting the FeatureManager into my code sections and utililzing the feature tag in .cshtml files like so,

```
<feature name="Beta">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Beta" asp-action="Index">Beta</a>
    </li>
</feature>
```

However, I have not been able to successfully use the feature tag in my .razor files. This comes as a result of not being able to add this directive to my files.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.FeatureManagement.AspNetCore
```

Is there a way to use the feature tag in my Razor files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK Blazor does not yet have a similar component/tag-helper. But not to worry - it's quite easy to check the flags manually.

```cs
@using Microsoft.FeatureManagement
@inject IFeatureManager FeatureManager

@if (betaFeatureIsEnabled)
{
    <h1>My Beta Feature</h1>
}

@code {
    private bool betaFeatureIsEnabled = false;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        betaFeatureIsEnabled = await FeatureManager.IsEnabledAsync("Beta");
    }
}
```

From this we can roll our own little helper component to make this look quite neat.

#### FeatureFlagView.razor (helper component)

```cs
@using Microsoft.FeatureManagement
@inject IFeatureManager FeatureManager

@if (featureIsEnabled)
{
    @ChildContent
}

@code {
    private bool featureIsEnabled = false;

    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string FlagName { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FlagName)) return;
        featureIsEnabled = await FeatureManager.IsEnabledAsync(FlagName);
    }
}
```

#### Using the FeatureFlagView inside a .razor page/component

```html
<FeatureFlagView FlagName="Beta">
    <h1>My Beta Feature</h1>
</FeatureFlagView>
```

This could then be extended quite a bit to handle more complex scenarios like requiring multiple flags, not flags etc and more importantly using Enum's (instead of strings).